Transactional interpretation of quantum mechanics, again
Up to now, I appreciated various interpretations of quantum mechanics, namely, the Copenhagen interpretation, the many-worlds interpretation, the decoherence interpretation, and the Bohm's pilot wave.
Instead I could not understand at all the "transactional interpretation". It is usually described in analogy to something else, e.g. theories of electromagnetic field. I get lost because I do not see any clear description of the interpretation per se. Some other times, the first half of a paper is devoted to the classification of abstract models, which I can hardly follow because I do not have practical examples; when the examples are given, then, they are described with the jargon of the previous abstract classification, so I hardly follow them.
At variance with previous questions on this topic, here I would like to have the explanation of a single example with the transactional interpretation, e.g. the double slit experiment.
I see that many people think that the transactional interpretation is a complete non-sense. I would like to get answers from supporters of the transactional interpretation, so, please, save the criticism for the comments.
Alternatively, possible answers can focus on original ideas to improve the transactional interpretation, or ideas inspired by transactional interpretation that can be useful in general.

Have you tried reading the book on that?

No, I did not read the book. I tried reading the website with the same name, but I did not understand anything, not even the structure of the website. I also read some papers from Kramer, with similar result. Also, I read something in internet, e.g. wikipedia and other questions in this website. If you read the book, can you please explicitly confirm that it is worth trying?

bought Kastner's book but sadly not sufficient time to read it. kinda like the idea though. If it is problematic, it is at least not obviously so.

On your last point:  The class of approaches inspired by the transactional interpretation are more generally called "retrocausal" or "future input dependent" models of quantum phenomena.  There is still no complete interpretation/reformulation of quantum theory from this perspective, but there are a number of toy models which use future constraints to explain what is happening between measurements, along the lines of what has been attempted in the transactional interpretation.

@Ken Wharton: actually, I heared something about the things you mention, but I could not find any clear analysis of them. Can you provide some literature reference? Or, even better, explain your favorite "toy model" as an answer? I think that it would be valuable for the community (even if my question did not get any vote).

@DorianoBrogioli: Here's the arXiv version of the big review paper from "Reviews of Modern Physics"; https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.04313 .  The most successful toy model is known as the "Schulman Model", which can handle any two-qubit maximally entangled state.  It's recently been extended to 3-qubit GHZ states here: https://arxiv.org/abs/2401.09398 .  There's still no complete retrocausal model of partially entangled states.

You can see a ten-minute-long account of how the Schulman model works from 15:00-25:00 in this talk of mine from many years ago: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qVUdrCooGA8 .  My claims at the end about generalizing to any quantum state were new results that turned out to have technical problems.

@Ken Wharton: my difficulty with all these theories is that they are explained starting with a long classification of theoretical cases, which I find difficult to follow because they are too much abstract. I hardly understand what they mean. Then, when the practical examples are given, they are explained in therms of the classifications above,  thus I do not understan them as well. Apart from this difficulty: what I would like to see is how to insert (some weak form of) retrocausality into logical circuits, getting (a sort of) hidden-variable version of quantum circuits. Is it feasible?

@DorianoBrogioli: Yes, I absolutely think that using quantum circuits is the right approach, and the only way to make such models general.  And I think it's feasible, too.  But no one has managed it yet -- stay tuned for my next paper and we'll see how close we can get.  (I assume that by a "weak form" you mean that any retrocausation would be down at the level of hidden variables, preventing signaling into the past.)

@KenWharton: I am looking forward to see your next paper, then! It seems that you are exactly going in the direction I was asking. And, yes, for "some sort of weak form" I mean that it avoids to send information back in time. More precisely, it is weak enough that it does not allow to design circuits that do not have solutions, like a NOT gate whose input is connected to the output.

@KenWharton: I see in literature that you are trying to study models that do not work like "time evolution of a state" (not "a computer" in your language)! I felt like the only one in the world pursuing such a goal (in my spare time). I have the feeling that the main difficulty of such models is that we are obliged (somehow) to embed the observed inside them: "what would an observer see if the laws were like this?" I tried to formalize this (unfortunately, still only for "computer-like" models): https://philsci-archive.pitt.edu/19509/ I would be grateful if you give me your opinion!

@naturallyinconsistent : I tried to read the book, but, after so many months, I still do not understand anything. Did you read the book? Can you suggest a specific page we can discuss?

@DorianoBrogioli Which book do you have? Based on your comments, I think this book would be the best place for you to start: https://www.amazon.com/Quantum-Handshake-Entanglement-Nonlocality-Transactions/dp/3319246402

I tried with the book "The transactional interpretation of quantum mechanics, The Reality of Possibility" by R. E. Kastner. @Gilbert: if you understood the book, I would appreciate very much an answer to this question, with a simple example.

Below, I will quote John Cramer's TI narrative of the two-slit experiment from his book:
[1] Cramer, J. G. (2016). The Quantum Handshake: Entanglement, Nonlocality and Transactions. Springer International Publishing.
As a little background (at least my understanding of it), a "transaction" refers to the transfer of a quantum particle (containing a quantum of energy/momentum/spin/etc.) between an emitter and an absorber. Suppose the emitter is ready to emit a photon. This occurs via the emission of an "offer wave" (i.e. a retarded, or forward-time-propagating, wavefunction). The offer wave interacts with all potential absorber atoms in its path, inducing the generation of "confirmation waves" (i.e. advanced, or backward-time-propagating, wavefunctions). These confirmation waves travel back in time to the emitter. One of these confirmation waves is "selected" (the TI version of wavefunction collapse), and the quantum transmission of a particle occurs.
In this conception, "emission" and "absorption" cannot be thought of as individual events; rather, they are a single event of "transmission" stretched across time and space. As Gilbert N. Lewis wrote, "I may say that my eye touches a star, not in the same sense as when I say that my hand touches a pen, but in an equally physical sense."
Selection of a confirmation wave is described as an analogy to spontaneous symmetry breaking, wherein (in the example of photon transmission) "perturbations of emitter and absorber acting on each other create a frequency-matched pair of dipole resonators as mixed states, and this dynamically unstable system either exponentially avalanches to the formation of a complete transaction, or it disappears when a competing transaction forms" (1, p. 66-7). Quantum randomness emerges because, "in a universe full of particles, this process does not occur in isolation, and both emitter and absorber are also randomly perturbed by waves from other systems that can randomly drive the exponential instability in either direction" (1, p. 67).
So here's the description of the two-slit experiment (1, p. 77), where light is emitted propagating to the right from the source emitter toward the slits and finally the photosensitive screen (labeled C):

The source emits plane offer waves...[that] pass through both slits...and arrive at any point on screen C from two directions. At locations along screen C where the two components of the offer wave interfere  constructively there is a high probability  of transaction, and at locations where the two components of the offer wave interfere destructively and cancel there is zero probability of a transaction. Confirmation waves propagate to the left, moving back through the slits...to the light source. There the source, which is seeking to emit one photon, selects among the confirmation offers, and a transaction delivers a photon to screen C. The position at which the photon arrives is likely to be where the offer waves were constructive and unlikely to be where the waves were destructive. Therefore, the interference pattern made of many single photon transactions builds up on screen C....


Please, confirm these things. 1) When the transaction takes place, we get the actual, total wave, which is the sum of the offer and the confirmation waves. 2) The total wave is present only in the time range between the events of emission and adsorption: the offer and confirmation waves delete each other outside this time range. 3) The offer and confirmation waves follow the usual rules of classical electrodynamics, at least for the case you are dealing with, the exchange of a photon.

@DorianoBrogioli These questions reflect the one-dimensional perspective of the WF picture. In 3D, it's a little more subtle. (1) The transaction occurs when the offer/confirmation waves have built up in strength (and been suppressed elsewhere) to transfer one complete quantum of mass/energy/spin from emitter to absorber. (2) Yes, sort of, I suppose. (3) Yes, the offer/confirmation waves are the same wave functions which go into Maxwell's equations and behave accordingly. This results in the wave characteristics of the transaction, even if the transfer of energy/mass/spin is quantized.

I find it hard to accept that all these three things can happen together, can you help me understand? According to 3, the offer and confirmation waves follow Maxwell equation. The offer wave is emitted instantaneously in a single point (almost). Even if the emission is agreed through a complex procedure, the wave propagates as Maxwell wave. The same for the confirmation wave. Than, it is impossible that the sum of the two vanishes outside the time range between the events. Am I wrong?

@DorianoBrogioli I don't consider myself an expert on this; I'm just interpreting what I read in the above book a while ago. That said, I think you're right. The sum of the two don't exactly vanish outside the time range. But they don't have to since the transaction isn't "selected" until the constructive interference between the emitter and absorber builds up to a full quantum of strength (and everything else diminishes to zero). That's the crux of this whole thing, and I think to understand it best, you should go to the source (or maybe Kastner's book, which I haven't read).

I actually read two books and several papers on the topic but I did not understand them at all, that's why I am asking here. So, you say that the "selection of the transaction" makes it to "build up to a full quantum of strenght"; at that point, is the wave still following Maxwell or not? Does it "diminishes to zero" still remaining the solution of Maxwell equations?

@DorianoBrogioli The transaction selection is analogous to the collapse of the wavefunction in the Copenhagen interpretation. At that point, the transfer of energy/mass/spin is particle-like. I think Cramer's description of "frequency-matched pairs of dipole resonators...exponentially avalanch[ing] to the formation of a complete transaction" (note that this occurs in quasi-time since the confirmation waves are advanced) is a description of the transition from wave-like to particle-like behavior. A particle ends up transferred, but only to where it was likely to go based on wave dynamics.

This is a fundamental point! So the transaction is between two consecutive complete collapses of the wave function, or between a prepraration of a pure state and a measurement. Now that I understand this, it seems to me that the transactional interpretation is quite similar to the Copenhagen interpretation, just more time-symmetric. There is no attempt to explain what happens in between, but just how the wave collapses "agree" among each other. Please correct me if I am wrong!
