Wheeler-Feynman electromagnetic theory and the "transactional interpretation"
I am trying to understand the so-called "transactional interpretation" of quantum mechanics. I do not understand it at all and I am wondering if it makes sense or not. I already tried to ask in this forum but I did not get satisfactory answers.
Then I try again, asking about a specific paper: John G. Cramer, The transactional interpretation of quantum mechanics.
In pages 660-663, the Wheeler-Feynman formulation of electromagnetism is given. The Author claims that, using this formulation, it is possible to describe the exchange of a photon between two charged particles, without the need of quantum mechanics. I do not clearly understand the reasoning, but it seems to me that the Author claims that it is possible to find a solution of the classical electromagnetic equations, such that an electromagnetic wave is emitted by a particle at a given time and then completely adsorbed by another one at a subsequent time.
Maybe I am misunderstanding the paper, but I would appreciate any comment.

No, you are reading the paper slightly wrongly. The WF classical electromagnetism is only covered in Appendix section A on page 659, although parts of it had been extracted out and pushed to the other pages that you are referencing. It is quite incomplete if you only read the small section, but it would be a mix of quantum and classical variations on the theme if you read all of those sections.

Actually, I am not trying to understand the WF theory but rather the "transactional interpretation". I also tried to read the book you suggested me in the comment to the other question! Do you think that it is possible to understand the "transactional interpretation" without first studying the WF theory?

Have you seen Ruth Kastner's work on the TI? https://transactionalinterpretation.org/

@DorianoBrogioli My understanding is that the WF theory is in some sense a subset of TI. WF theory is specifically concerning EM waves, whereas TI extends the idea to wavefunctions in general (i.e. time-symmetric waves emitted by both an "emitter" and "absorber" leading to constructive interference in the timeline between them and destructive interference elsewhere (elsewhen?)). I don't think you need to read the WF paper first.

Yes, I tried to read this book. I do not understand it. There is a lot of philosophy, which I find hard to follow, because I do not see practical examples. Then the physics starts but is explained based on the philosophy above. I would appreciate very much to have a single, clear example of this "transactional interpretation", see https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/817298/

To be more specific, let us look at fig 4 of the paper. Is the wave the electromagnetic wave? Then, I really do not think that there can be such a 4d standing wave. Is it possible? If not, what are these waves?

Like you I was puzzled by Cramer's Handshake, I bought his book and even emailed him only to get the suggestion I should buy his book - I think this was some sort of cyclic social handshake I also didn't understand.
My problem with Cramer is the lack of equations, in his book he does give basic wavefunctions and diagrams, but there is very little way of explanation in the way of underlying physics as to why the past and the future are pressing flesh, honestly I think there is more handwaving than handshaking in Cramer's model.
You could also look at Milo Wolff's A Wave Structure for the Electron[https://mwolff.tripod.com/point.html] , now at least with Wolff he gives equations that perform some task, his model has a detailed description of how the Wheeler-Feynman Time-Symmetric Theory connects the past to the future and I think overall Milo's approach makes a lot of sense. There is a lot of commonality between Wolff's argument and Cramer's point and they are probably saying the same thing, time will tell, and having said that I also essentially agree with Wolff and Cramer's models but not their expositions.
Having said that I think there is a way to say the exact same thing using electromagnetism and quantum mechanics in a way that eliminates ambiguity and gives testable results without the handwaving.
I think the essential idea is to model matter as a longitudinal electromagnetic wave using the scalar potential φ to generate the electron's charge, mass, spin, wavelength and classical velocity in a series of steps similar to Maxwell's modelling light as a transverse electromagnetic wave.
By using Maxwell's original potential formulation of φ and A instead of Oliver Heaviside's field formulation of E and B, where the scalar potential exists along the axis of time $R^1$ and it not restricted in the same way as the E and B fields are in $R^{1,3}$, the model uses a variation of the Wheeler-Feynman Time Symmetric model (WFTSM), where instead of using Wheeler's and Feynman's field formulation for the WFTSM it uses the four-vector potentials, $A_μ$
$$E_{total} + E_{free} = ∑_n 1/2 ( E_{ret} + E_{adv})  +  ∑_n 1/2 ( E_{ret} - E_{adv}) = ∑_n E_{ret}$$
Instead we can use the four-vector potential $A_μ$ in the summation
$$A_μ^{free} + A_μ^{total} = ∑_n 1/2 (A_μ^{ret} - A_\mu^{adv}) + ∑n 1/2 (Aμret+Aμadv)  = ∑_n A_μ^{ret}$$
Where the original charges of the advanced and retarded charges are hidden inside the scalar potentials φ of the $A_{μ}$, as a result this places the sources for the $A_μ$ forward and backwards in time, this can be shown to greatly simplify the WFTSM as well as giving a means to construct the electron as a hollow charged spinning sphere similar to Poincaré and Abraham's model way back in the early 1900s which had its roots in the Liénard–Wiechert potentials (check Wikipedia on them).
To do this we will need to jump between the Coulomb and Lorenz gauges as we go from $R^{1,3}$ to $R^{3}$ and back again to $R^{1,3}$, where firstly the magnetic component A is dropped in the Coulomb gauge as the A does not translate across time and the WFTSM is solved purely in terms of the φ components,
$$φ_{total} + φ_{free}  = ∑_n 1/2 (φ_{ret} +φ_{adv})+∑_n 1/2 (φ_{ret} - φ_{adv})  = ∑_n φ_{ret}$$
This may seem going back to Wheeler and Feynman's original formulation the model does eventually return to the four-vector notation, but more importantly since the scalar potential lies entirely along the axis of time it does something fundamentally different from the fields, or to quote David Griffiths in his Introduction to Electrodynamics:
"There is a very peculiar thing about the scalar potential in the Coulomb gauge: it is determined by the distribution of charge right now. If I move an electron in my laboratory, the potential V on the moon immediately records this change. That sounds particularly odd in the light of special relativity, which allows no message to travel faster than c. The point is that V by itself is not a physically measurable quantity – all the man in the Moon can measure is E, and that involves A as well." [Griffiths 2017, p441]
This means the scalar potential can appear far in the future or the past without the exchange of energy or information, and the resultant scalar potential appears in the local frame  $φ_{int}$  (or internal or intrinsic potential) and relative to this are the external frames $φ_{ext}$ (or the external or extrinsic) of the advanced and retarded frames in the non-local frames, that is the intrinsic scalar potential arises from exterior potentials, allowing us to write the WFTSM as,
$$φ_{int} = φ_{total} + φ_{free}  = ∑_n 1/2 (φ_{ret} + φ_{adv})+∑_{n} 1/2 (φ_{ret} - φ_{adv})  = ∑_n φ_{ext}$$
Importantly where for a moving particle the φ is varying with time, and this requires we must return to the Lorenz gauge in $R^{1,3}$ where in order to satisfy Maxwell's equations in the local or internal frame - the A reappears as the local or intrinsic magnetic vector potential $A_{int}$
$$∇ ⋅ A_{int}  = \frac{-1}{c}  \frac{ ∂φ_{ext}}{∂t}$$
(Note this is a critical step) for it also introduces a new four-vector potential $A_μ^{int}$
$$A_μ^{int} = (φ_{ext}/c, A_{int})$$
That reconstructs the four-vector potential in the local frame, however, once more in order to satisfy Maxwell's equations we must also introduce a new B field with the A,
$$\textbf{B} = ∇ × \textbf{A}$$
which immediately leads to the Maxwell–Ampère equation with introduction of J and the E,
$$∇ × \textbf{B} = μ_0 \textbf{J} + μ_0 ε_0  ∂\textbf{E}/∂t$$
In the presence of a charge, the above can be reworked to give a longitudinal scalar electromagnetic wave (longitudinal along the axis of time),
$$∇^2 φ - 1/c^2 ∂^2 φ/∂t^2 = ρ/ε_0$$
I think this is the point where this model becomes equivalent to Maxwell's model for Light, and it does so without violating conservation of energy, momentum or charge. This equation is one of Maxwell's original 20 equations or potentials and fields to model electromagnetism, and but it doesn't appear Oliver Heaviside's 4 electromagnetic field equations.
The charge is "there" but it is derived from the relative position of the advanced and retarded potentials, which means there is no local charge in this model, and if there is no local charge then the electron has been reduced to purely external potentials, in effect, the electron has become a longitudinal scalar electromagnetic wave and it does so without violating conservation of energy, momentum or charge.
Note that Wolff does have this second order wave equation in his papers but I don't quite see how he derives it. (anyone know much about Milo Wolff?)
In this model electrons turn into perfect spheres, which is something that was pushed back in 1902 by Max Abraham and Henri Poincaré.
It can be shown [see linked papers at end of this letter] the curl of the B appears on the surface of a sphere with the electron radius because to satisfy the Coulomb gauge and Maxwell–Ampère equation the sphere must be spinning, implying the electron itself is spinning or we have a spinning magnetic charged particle in $R^3$ , this was also shown to have the classical velocity of the electron and a wave function with the Reduced Compton wavelength in $R^{1,3}$, given by $ ∇^2 φ - 1/c^2 ∂^2 φ/∂t^2 = ρ/ε_0$ ,
The fields E and B do not appear until after the transformation from the Coulomb gauge into the Lorenz gauge takes place, and appear at the sum of the $φ_{adv}$ and $φ_{ret}$ vectors on the envelope of the sphere. There is nothing of the electron in the local frame within the sphere and this removes the problem of infinite self-energy for the classical point electron particles as now the particle is distributed between the past and the future. The appearance of the E and B do not violate conservation of energy as the current density carries the charge with it along the axis of time. The minima and maxima of the longitudinal wave appear at the position of the advanced and retarded particles within the classical de Broglie reduced 1/4 wavelengths; and in the above diagram the $R^{1,3}$ waveform is superimposed on the $R^3$ charged spinning sphere.

The following is a discussion of Wave equations (and is very similar to Wolff's model)
It is now that the choice of the four-vector potential as our starting point is understood as it allows us to write the wavefunction in terms of the phase of $A_μ$ which contains all the information necessary to derive the Dirac equation from the wavefunction,
$$ψ = exp[  i/2 ℏ ∫ A_μ dx_μ]$$
We can now reapply Wheeler-Feynman summation to the very wavefunctions themselves,
$$ψ_{ret} = exp[i /2 ℏ  ∫ A_μ^{ret} dx_μ + ε_{ret} ]$$
$$ψ_{adv} = exp[-i /2 ℏ  ∫ A_μ^{adv} dx_μ + ε_{adv}]$$
where the epoch angles $ε_{ret}$ and $ε_{adv}$ take the place of the free potentials,
$$ε_{ret} = i /2 ℏ ∫ A_μ^{adv}  dx_μ$$
$$ε_{adv} = i /2 ℏ ∫ A_μ^{ret} dx_μ$$
these half-wave functions represent the four vector potentials being projected equal into the past and future, and where
$$ε_{ret} = - ε_{adv}$$
This is a necessary step to ensure the advanced and retarded potentials are in phase and have equal energies, this is the only difference between Wheeler and Feynman's original model but even Feynman pointed out there was something not quite right in their assumption that the free particles constituted all the free particles in the universe, in this present model this problem is eliminated and is reduced to a simple phase correlation.
We can now rewrite the Wheeler-Feynman summation purely in terms of half-wave functions as,
$$ Ψ_{total} =  e i/ℏ ∫ (1/2 A_μ^{ret} + 1/2 A_μ^{adv}  + 1/2  A_μ^{ret}  - 1/2 A_μ^{adv}) dx_μ$$
which after summation reduces to a full wavefunction,
$$Ψ_{total} = e i / ℏ ∫ A_μ dx_μ  = Ψ_{int}  = Ψ_{ret}$$
To derive the Dirac equation we equate the phases to the four-vector phase of the wavefunction,
$$p_μ x^μ = ∫ q A_μ dx^μ$$
and take the inner product of the four-momentum,
$$p_μ p^μ = (E/c)^2 - p ⋅ p  =  - m^2 c^2 $$
on rearranging to give the relativistic energy-momentum relation,
$$E^22 = (pc)^2 + (mc^2)^2$$
besides equating the phases of the advanced and retarded particles we must also include their orientation or spin the axis of which is determined by the orientation of B = ∇ × A, and this requires introducing the Dirac matrices γ_μ and Dirac spinors u(p, ω) to act on the wavefunctions,
$$ψ(x,t) = u(p, ω) e^{i (p ⋅ x - ω t)}$$
only after this can we write down the Dirac equation,
$$(i ℏ γ_μ ∂_μ  - mc) ψ = 0$$
Thus it can be seen that the Dirac equation can be directly derived from Maxwell's equations and the Wheeler-Feynman summation, the only difference from Wheeler and Feynman's model is the use of the adv and ret epoch angles instead of all the free particles in the universe.
If we now make a set of identities,
$$|ψ_{ret}|=|ψ_{adv}|$$
$$ψ_{ret} = ψ_{adv}^* $$
$$ψ_{adv} = ψ_{ret}^*$$
$$ψ_{ret} ⋅ ψ_{ret}^* = I $$
$$ψ_{total} = ψ_{ret} ⋅ ψ_{adv}$$
where the interference between the advanced and retarded wave-functions is identity matrix I,
$$ψ_{interference} = ψ_{ret} ⋅ ψ_{adv}^* = I$$
Now re-formulate the Wheeler-Feynman summation in its most elegant form,
$$Ψ_{total}  = ψ_{total} ⋅  ψ_{interference} $$
$$     = ψ_{ret} ⋅ ψ_{adv} ⋅ ψ_{ret} ⋅ ψ_{adv}^* $$
$$     = ψ_{ret} ⋅ ψ_{ret}^* ⋅ ψ_{ret} ⋅ ψ_{ret}^{**} $$
$$     = ψ_{ret} ⋅ ψ_{ret}^* ⋅ ψ_{ret} ⋅ ψ_{ret} $$
$$    = ψ_{ret} ⋅ ψ_{ret} $$
$$      = Ψ_{ret}    $$
$$   ≡ Ψ_{intrinsic}$$
Thus all the characteristics of the electron can be constructed in much the same way as Maxwell was able to construct the characteristics of the electromagnetic wave that would become the photon. Where the critical steps are assuming the Wheeler-Feynman summation; using the electromagnetic vector potential Aμ instead of Heavside's E and B field formulation; switching back and forth between the Coulomb and Lorenz gauges to satisfy Maxwell's equations; and finally equating the phases and orientation of the adv and retarded particles to yield the Dirac equation.
Pictorially it should look similar to the intersection of two four-dimensional spheres along the axis of time, which in 2D projection appears as a magnetic field B ringed around the axis of time as according to the Ampere-Maxwell's law, in 4D the ring is actually a sphere lying along the axis of time.
[spherical particle]
We can use the Parallelogram rule to construct a series of envelopes in three dimensions as charged spinning hollow spheres, as well as a progression of waveforms derived from the phases given by the four-vector along the time axis $$A_μ → A_η → A_ν  → A_ζ → A_ε → A_δ  $$

The model predicts an external 3-Spheres double-covering of the electrons and implicitly yields the 720 degrees necessary for Spin, charge, mass  for the electron, and it predicts a classical electron velocity, an exact value for the reduced Compton wavelength, and that the electron is perfectly spherical. You should do a search for spherical electron here on StackExchange (What does it mean to say that the electron is a near-perfect sphere?)
If this interests you then please consider the attached papers.
A Dynamical Theory of the Electromagnetic Four-Potential
The Dirac Equation and the Wheeler-Feynman Time-Symmetric Theory
Spherical Electrons and the Wheeler-Feynman Time-Symmetric Theory
Zitterbewegung and the Wheeler-Feynman Time-Symmetric Theory
The Arrow of Time and the Wheeler-Feynman Time-Symmetric Theory
Well Doriano I hope this points you in the right direction.

Thanks for the extensive answer! It raises extensive questions... The Psi you discuss is something that describes the electromagnetic field, is it correct? Where does it switch to represent matter? Maybe, a summary clarifying the general meaning could be helpful.

To which I shall attempt an extensive reply... The $\Psi$ is the normal wavefunction of matter, really no different from the standard symbol in quantum mechanics, you can see its use on page 59 of Cramer's 2016 book. Psi is a function of the four-vector potential which contains all the information for an electromagnetic wave, and that's the trick, hidden inside the exponential of the wavefunction is the Wheeler-Feynman sum $$A_μ^{free} + A_μ^{total} = ∑_n 1/2 (A_μ^{ret} - A_\mu^{adv}) + ∑n 1/2 (A_μ^{ret}+A_μ^{adv})  = ∑_n A_μ^{ret}$$

That can be worked to give a wavefunction of the scalar potential, or $$ ∇^2 φ - 1/c^2 ∂^2 φ/∂t^2 = ρ/ε_0 $$, and then afterwards the $A_\mu$ is worked to give the wavefunction $$ψ = exp[  i/2 ℏ ∫ A_μ dx_μ]$$

continuing part 2: So in answer to your question - it doesn't actually switch, it is an electromagnetic field all the time, I'm suggesting electrons and fermions in general move as electromagnetic waves in time but are charge particles in space. Sorry for the multiple replies we can only edit for five minutes in comments which makes it hard to write equations.

Summarizing, you propose some equations and constraints for some fields; then you manipulate these equations showing that you can derive some fields mimicking the electromagnetic wave and some other field mimicking Dirac's electron equation. Is this correct?

Pretty much correct, however, the equations are all standard electromagnetism and quantum mechanics, the only constraint between this and orthodox physics is changing where the absorbers appear, in the Wheeler-Feynman model they postulated "a model all charges in the universe with a uniform absorber in a shell around a charge" . While I substituted the absorber to the epoch angles of the adv and ret particles, this necessarily sets the phase to equality, and this lends itself to Dirac's equation. Uniquely this yields an exact value of Reduced Compton wavelength - I'm proud of that result.

Impressive! But I still have a question slightly outside the original topic. This work seems to aim at a coherent field theory, reconciling electrodynamics and Dirac's equation. Still, these fields must be handled by conventional methods to get the quantum outcomes, like Dirac's equation requires a kind of "quantization" to give quantum mechanics. From this point of view, the aim appears different from "transactional interpretation", which pretends to explain in details how quantum mechanics works. Is this correct?

I think Cramer’s T.I. captures the essence of the Wheeler-Feynman sum without explanation, and while Woolf’s Quantum Wave Structure does gives a quantum mechanical causation he makes jumps in his assumptions I don’t understand, so I simplified the whole thing and made the model more about the electrodynamics rather than the quantum mechanical. The Dirac eqn just appears I only noticed it when I saw the four-vector potential $A_\mu$ was what Feynman used in his work. But yes, T.I. “seems to pretend to explain in details”, and I just don’t get what is the mechanism doing the handshaking.

Put it another way, consider that a photon is an EM wave that is emitted by an electron, but we don’t have a 2nd order wave equation for the electron what we use are either the Schrödinger or Dirac equations but they are not 2nd order wave equations which is a bit odd because throughout the literature you see them referred to as wave equations, and while the Klein–Gordon equation is 2nd order that’s not what we use to describe the electron. So, if a photon is an EM wave and an electron is an electromagnetic particle then at some level there has to be a 2nd order wave EM equation explaining it.

I see the point and I think it is interesting. However, all this discussion does not support the claims of the "transactional interpretation"!

On that, yes, we have an agreement, TI just seems to hang in the theoretical air without a foundation, honestly I'm not even sure you could call TI a theory. If you're looking a reasonable model then again I would suggest looking at Milo Woolf's Wave Structure of Particles https://mwolff.tripod.com, he gets a bit enthusiastic at times but he does have equations that can be readily understood. Just one last note, you know Maxwell actually wrote 20 equations but we only use 4, and one of those 20 is a 2nd order wave equation for the scalar potential $$∇^2 φ - 1/c^2 ∂^2 φ/∂t^2 = ρ/ε_0$$ thanks.
